# Dynamically created progress bars - wrong child order?

Tags: android

I have a custom control where I need to create a number of `ProgressBar`s with specific style, and add them to a `LinearLayout` container, with some even spacing (with the only modification after creation being setting the progress, and setting 0 starting margin on the first, and 0 ending margin for the last items).

I'm using the following code to create the `ProgressBar` instances:

```
if (container.childCount != progressSteps) {
    container.removeAllViews()
    repeat(progressSteps) {
        container.addView(generateProgressBar())
    }
    container.children.first().apply {
        layoutParams = (layoutParams as LinearLayout.LayoutParams).apply {
            marginStart = 0
        }
    }
    container.children.last().apply {
        layoutParams = (layoutParams as LinearLayout.LayoutParams).apply {
            marginEnd = 0
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the bit that's supposed to be updating the progress status of each:

```
(0 until container.childCount).forEach { index ->
    val child = container[index]
    val shouldTint = index < currentProgress
    (child as ProgressBar).progress = if (shouldTint) 100 else 0
}
```

Explanation:

- `container` is my `LinearLayout` meant to contain the `ProgressBar` instances
- `progressSteps` and `currentProgress` are `Int` variable properties on my View class
- `generateProgressBar()` creates a `ProgressBar` instance with some custom styling (basically using the `android.R.attr.progressBarStyleHorizontal` style, overriding the `progressDrawable` and some layout params)

What I end up with is the last `ProgressBar` getting tinted, however according to the LayoutInspector dump, the first two should be. But they stay gray.